# Using np.loadtxt between two specific lines (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, data-extraction

I know that np.loadtxt allows you to quickly extract data from columns in a text file, and I know that you can use `skiprows` to skip the first N number of rows. Can you specify an *end* line number, such that np.loadtxt only extracts text between two known line numbers in a text file?

In the following example, you can specify:

`(dat1,dat2) = np.loadtxt(file, skiprows = 1, usecols = (0,1), unpack=True)`

but I get an error saying that "ValueError: could not convert string to float: Data1"

Example:

`1    Data1  Data2  Data3
2      1      3      5
3      7      1      6
[...]
48     8      9      2
49     2      7      6
50    Data1  Data2  Data3
51     5      6      1
52     9     12      3
53     1      0      2`

Comment: `genfromtxt` has a max lines parameter

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for, especially given `genfromtxt` description: "numpy.loadtxt -- equivalent function when no data is missing."  If you make your response a solution, I will accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.genfromtxt` with

```
skip_header : int, optional
    The number of lines to skip at the beginning of the file.
skip_footer : int, optional
    The number of lines to skip at the end of the file.
max_rows : int,  optional
    The maximum number of rows to read. Must not be used with skip_footer
    at the same time.  If given, the value must be at least 1. Default is
    to read the entire file.
```

gives a lot of control over which lines are read.

Another option is to open the file yourself, e.g.

```
with open('myfile', 'rb') as f:
     <skip>
     np.genfromtxt(f, ...)
     etc
```

and pass it to `genfromtxt`.  You can even feed it line by line.  `genfromtxt` (and `loadtxt`) is happy with anything that feeds it lines - a file, a list of lines, a generator of lines, etc.